# Android - Pressing back button on fragment just re-opens the same fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation, fragment

Activity:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, Fragment_1.newInstance())
                .commitNow()
```

My first fragment:

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
            .replace(R.id.container, nextFrag, "Fragment_2")
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

Pressing on the back button opens the first fragment for a second then reopens the second fragment I'm trying to close. Can somebody please explain why this is happening? I tried overriding the back button to pop the stack but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack()
}
```

[EDIT]
Okay so after some looking into, the problem isn't coming from the fragments at all. The issue is coming from a view model observer re-executing when going back to Fragment_1.

```
viewModel.error.observe(this, Observer {
     viewModel.goFragment_2(activity!!)
})
```

I'm not sure why this observer re-executes...

Comment: Instead of `activity.supportFragmentManager` try using `childFragmentManager`

Answer (score 0):

Why you used this code in fragment?

```
activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
        .replace(R.id.container, nextFrag, "Fragment_2")
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
```

use in your ACTIVITY.
I think it will do well!

Comment: I'm trying to open Fragment_2 from a button click inside Fragment_1